# running eclipse on linux, "eclipse is not executable."

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, opensuse

I have just downloaded the android sdk for linux. I am running OpenSuse 12.3. When I try to run eclipse, there is an error that says that there is no program to run executable files. So I use the following  ways to make the eclipse program executable.

1. Right click the program and opening the 'properties' option to check the 'allow executing file as program' checkbox. But as soon as I check the box, it gets unchecked and I am not able to run eclipse.
2. I tried using the chmod +x command but there was no change.

How do I make eclipse executable? Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're trying to run eclipse but this is the right way to do it:

- from terminal, change directory into the eclipse folder(since you downloaded the adt bundle, the eclipse folder can be  found in the extracted adt bundle folder)
- then run this command: `sudo ./eclipse`
  that should work fine. You can check this blog for more details on how to set up your android environment. I believe it will work just fine in OpenSuse as well: [How To Set Up Your Android Environment On Ubuntu](http://euniceadu.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/how-to-set-up-your-android-environment-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

There is ADT Bundle for Linux, are you sure that you've downloaded the correct one?

[This](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130729.zip) is for linux 32bit